# Haskell doctest does not load package managed with cabal-dev

Tags: haskell, cabal, doctest

I am trying to test my project which uses "data-binary-ieee754" with doctests.

I uses cabal-dev, instead of cabal, to manage package dependencies.
I can build the project, but doctest seems not to recognize that package.

doctests definition in .cabal:

```
test-suite doctests
  type:            exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:  test
  main-is:         doctests.hs
  ghc-options:     -Wall -threaded
  build-depends:   base,
                   doctest >= 0.7,
                   data-binary-ieee754
```

test/doctests.hs:

```
module Main where

import Test.DocTest

main :: IO ()
main = doctest ["src/Pattern.hs"]
```

The error message for `cabal-dev test doctests` is:

```
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite doctests: RUNNING...

src/Pattern.hs:13:8:
    Could not find module `Data.Binary.IEEE754'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Test suite doctests: FAIL
Test suite logged to: dist/test/othello-0.1.0-doctests.log
0 of 1 test suites (0 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

I tried to add some options to doctests.hs, like

```
main = doctest ["--optghc=-Lcabal-dev/lib",
                "--optghc=-packagedata-binary-ieee754",
                "src/Pattern.hs"]
```

but the result is

```
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite doctests: RUNNING...
doctests: <command line>: cannot satisfy -package data-binary-ieee754
    (use -v for more information)
Test suite doctests: FAIL
Test suite logged to: dist/test/othello-0.1.0-doctests.log
0 of 1 test suites (0 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

Tell me how to do this correctly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer by myself.

http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6133 was helpful.

```
main :: IO ()
main = doctest ["--optghc=-Lcabal-dev/lib",
                "--optghc=-packagedata-binary-ieee754",
                "--optghc=-package-conf=cabal-dev/packages-7.4.1.conf",
                "src/Pattern.hs"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this answer a bit, doctest now allows you to call ghc options directly.
You can also load a sandboxed package database and call from cabal.

```
doctest [ "-package-db .cabal-sandbox/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3-packages.conf.d"
        , "-isrc"
        , "src/<path-to-file>"]
```

This cleared up missing package problems for me.